# React native + SAML + OKTA

Tags: react-native, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta

I am very new to react-native developing and my requirement is to integrate OKTA with react native app. After a lot of research i came to know i can do it using Okta mobile SDK which in turn needs SAML integration to my native app. so i need to add SAML support to my native app,but i am not getting any information in browser how to add SAML to my app.[OKTA Mobile SDK](https://developer.okta.com/use_cases/mobile/okta_mobile_connect)...

can any help me